# Очень странный баг

Tags: android, java

Добрый вечер. Вчера закончил модуль приложения, протестировал его на эмуляторе и физическом устройстве - все идеально. Сегодня запускаю приложение - как ни странно работает не так. При том код не изменился. Совсем.

Коротко о задаче:
Есть БД SQLite. В нем таблица. В таблице есть поле content. Если оно заполнено чем либо - вызывается один блок кода. Если пуста - другой. Так вот. Перестало работать условие.

Сама проблема:

```
void openNewActivity(long number){
    Log.d(TAG,"Starting openNewActivity");
    String selection = "parent_id=? and number=?";
    String selectionArgs[] = {"0",""+number}; //TODO: Костыль. Нужно найти способ исправить
    Cursor c = db.query("main", null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, "number");
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
            int contentColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("content");
            String id = c.getString(idColIndex);
            String content = c.getString(contentColIndex);
            Log.d(TAG,"["+content+"]"); //для проверки того, что эта переменная получена от БД. Скобки дабы избавить от пробелов.
            c.close();
            Log.d(TAG,"Id выбранного элемента в базе: " + id);
            if (content == null){
                if(db.isOpen()){
                    db.close();
                }
                Log.d(TAG,"Creating new menu");
                Intent intentNewMenu = new Intent(this, List.class); 
                intentNewMenu.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intentNewMenu);
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG,"Creating webview");

                if(db.isOpen()){
                    db.close();
                }

                Intent intentNewWebView = new Intent(this, OutWebView.class); 
                intentNewWebView.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intentNewWebView);
            }

          }
     }
```

Код конечно далеко не идеален, да я и не претендую. В общем не работает следущее условие:

```
if (content == null){}
```

Даже если забыть про то, что оно неясно как, но работало до этого можно предположить, что если допустим в БД вместо пустого поля писать none или тому подобное. Решение казалось бы элементарное. Да не тут то было. В такой ситуации получится следущее:

```
String content = c.getString(contentColIndex);
...
Log.d(TAG,"["+content+"]"); //Вернет [none]
...
 if (content == "none"){} //не сработает
```

Ок. Ну тогда попробуем сделать так, чтобы в обоих частях был String:

```
String compareString = "none";
if (content == compareString){}
```

Ага. Разбежались. Не сработает :D
Однако если поставить if (true) то блок выполнится

Я в замешательстве. Данная конструкция использовалась еще в одном активити. Тоже не работает.

p.s. Если кто подскажет как поправить костыль - буду благодарен. Объект number это long.
Буду рад даже предположениям. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: content == "none" сравнение двух указателей
т.е. верен тру если переменная указывает на одну и туже область памяти.
используйте 
"none".equals(content )

Comment: хмм, 2 месяца как подписался на рассылку java.* и чего то каждая третья проблема вызвана == :))) странно...

Comment: Великолепно! Но остается вопрос. Можно ли реализовать тоже самое но с пустым полем в бд. В таком случае этот способ не работает. На счет equals я все понял). Теперь их как минимум на 1 меньше :D.

Comment: а Ваши предположения какие? ;-)
Вы уверены, что c.getString(contentColIndex); возвращает нал?...если условие context == null не срабатывает, наверное оно не null, или я не прав?)

Comment: Нет не уверен. Но вчера же возвращал? Хотя ладно не важно :). Работает и ладно. Спасибо.

Comment: когда не очевидно, ведите отладочную печать, тем более Вы уже используете логгер.

Comment: String compareString = "none";
if (content == compareString){}

вообще строки в java сравниваются с помощью метода equels...

Comment: "Проблема" решена. Cursor возвращает просто пустой (не null) String. Таким образом нужно использовать content.equals(""), что я и сделал. Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: content.equals("") лучше заменить на content.isEmpty() - более кошерно. Чтобы не плодить полуоткрытые [s]соединения[/s] темы - создам ответ, и подытожу комментарии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подытожу все комментарии к вопросу, дабы автор мог закрыть вопрос...

БД может вернуть 'none' или пустую строку в данном случае, поэтому сравнивать нужно не только с null, но ещё и с этимb значениями.

В java и .NET недопустимо сравнивать строки через оператор сравнения (string==string). Оператор сравнения гарантирует только сравнение адресов объектов в памяти. Вернет true только в случаях: а) это один и тот же экземпляр строки б) строка есть в пуле (чего JVM не гарантирует во многих случаях).

Строки (да и вообще большинство объектов) необходимо сравнивать через метод Object.equals(Object), в конкретном случае: "none".equals(content) будет гарантировано правильно сравнивать.

Итого:

```
if (content == null || content.isEmpty() || "none".equals(content)){
// some code 1
} else {
// some code 2
}
```